# What criteria was used when selecting to attack humans?

Tags: movie, battleship

In the movie Battleship, the aliens seems to somehwhat discriminate whether or not to attack.  It was pretty obvious that when the aliens detected something as a threat, It would attack.  The converse seemed true, but it appeared that many "innocent" lives were not spared.  One scene in particular where the alien rolly-polly death machines attacked the interstate.  There didn’t seem to be an obvious threat, but many people did not make the attack.

**Am I missing something?**

Comment: It's based on the board game. You'd know the answer if you read up on your Hasbro mythos. I say that all as sarcastically as humanly possible.

Comment: Seeking logic in such a horribly written, plot-less movie is the first problem.  What's missing is 2+ hours of your life (and mine) horribly wasted that could have been given to any other more worthy endeavor, like watching grass grow.

Comment: @BBlake I can accept "horribly written" as answer :)

Comment: Criteria: Aim at the corners. Then at the center.

Comment: No discernible motivations exist for the aliens. Poor writing makes it impossible to come up with any plausible criteria. It was literally based off of the board game.

Comment: The real answer is: Of all the other planets they could have attacked, this one was most likely to have a movie made about it.

Comment: there were targeting human that did like the movie "Battleship". Such creatures can not be let to live.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the alien moves in 'Battleship' were pretty strategic (or at least thats what the scriptwriters intended!). Mindlessly attacking innocent lives (as in most alien invasion movies) was not needed because they posed no significant threats. We can see that the civilian causalities were mostly indirect (ship, interstate, airfield attacks).

Besides, it was just a pathfinder convoy from outer space. They were aware of their limitations to hold ground for longtime (until the invasion fleet reaches Earth). Taking out the nearest airfield and highways (within the barricade they created) ensured that the humans trapped in the areas within the barricade couldn't pose threat by any means (no air/ground support) and give them enough time to signal their dying home planet.

NB: Taking out enemy's airfields and pathways (roads) etc is the best way to fend off immediate resistance/movement. Its old military school stuff! You don't have to kill many for that...

Answer (score -3):

Simple: the interstate was a strategic target

Comment: This should be fleshed out to explain how it's a strategic target.